# Programa entra em looping indesejado - Arduino

Tags: c, arduino

O seguinte código deve, ao ser pressionado um botão, executar os comandos uma vez.
Se o usuário segurar o botão pressionado, o código também devera ser executado somente uma vez, como se fosse apenas um pulso no botão. Ao soltar o botão, o sistema deve estar pronto pra repetir a rotina.

Testei usando o Serial Monitor, e o código atende à minha necessidade, porem ao conectar o Arduíno ao sistema elétrico/eletrônico, o mesmo apresenta comportamento impreciso, as vezes obedecendo à rotina, as vezes entra em looping apos o primeiro acionamento do botão.

Alguém teria alguma dica pra me ajudar? Já estou a alguns dias tentando solucionar este problema, já refiz a programação de varias formas, mas sempre encontro este mesmo problema.

```
int x=0;
int ledVermelho = 8, ledVerde = 9, sensor = 12, aspersor = 7, cooler = 5; 
void setup() {
  pinMode(ledVermelho, OUTPUT);  //   seta o pino 9 como saÃ­da
  pinMode(ledVerde, OUTPUT);     //   seta o pino 10 como saÃ­da  
  pinMode(aspersor, OUTPUT);     //   seta o pino 11 como saÃ­da
  pinMode(cooler, OUTPUT);       //   seta o pino 12 como saida
  pinMode(sensor, INPUT);        //   seta o pino 13 como entrada
  digitalWrite(aspersor, LOW);   //    desliga o aspersor
  digitalWrite(cooler, LOW);            //    desliga o cooler
  digitalWrite(ledVermelho, LOW);       //    desliga o led vermelho
  digitalWrite(ledVerde, HIGH);         //    liga o led verde
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("aguardando ");

}
void loop() {
  if(digitalRead(sensor)){
    if(x==0){
      digitalWrite(aspersor, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(ledVerde, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledVermelho, HIGH);
      Serial.println("aspersor ativado");
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(aspersor, LOW);
      digitalWrite(cooler, HIGH);
      Serial.println("cooler ativado");
      delay(3000);
      digitalWrite(ledVermelho, LOW);
      digitalWrite(cooler, LOW);
      digitalWrite(ledVerde, HIGH);
      Serial.println("processo concluido");
    }
    x=1;
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("sensor desativado");
    x=0;
  }
}
```

Comment: Acredito que seja problema com o ruído mecânico do botão. Pesquise sobre *deboucing* que provavelmente resolverá seu problema.

Comment: O problema é debouncing como o Anderson indicou. Tanto pode resolver com hardware debouncing ou software debouncing. Comece por ler o que a documentação do Arduino já tem nesse sentido [aqui](https://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/SoftwareDebounce) e [aqui](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce)

Comment: Obrigado Anderson e Isac.
O problema era o ruido mesmo.
Solucionei com o software deboucing do link do Isac.
Sou novo no forum, não sei sinalizar como questão respondida ou algo do tipo.